# What is the use of installing Node.Js and angular CLI for angular 4/5 applications?

Tags: angular

I'm little confused can you please clarify the exact use of node and CLi in the angular projects.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) is a set of scripts that allows you to easily build and test Angular applications.  It gets y ou started building applications right away without having to focus on writing our own build processes for things like unit test execution or TypeScript compilation.

Angular CLI projects include a project structure, based on `our best practices` and that will help other developers maintain your code because you have a shared level of consistency.

Angular CLI also includes some helper scripts for building components which can help save you time.

Or to put it another way, I wrote my own build scripts and they took about a month.  Does your project have that much time in the budget / deadline?